# ExtJS localization using REST XML

Tags: xml, rest, extjs, localization

We are currently creating an ExtJS application. We have a requirement to implement i18n support.

The ExtJS application is being embedded to an existing web application (JBoss/Seam/whatever). This web application already has custom implementation of i18n support where localized text is stored in the DB.

We also have a requirement to reuse the existing facility, because they have external i18n client application where these keys/values can be altered at runtime.

As first attempt we created REST XML resources where we can get all keys/values for a given language (e.g. GET /i18n/en, GET /i18n/de etc) so it can be wired into ExtJS as the source of localization.

I'm currently googleing for about a day on how to wire this stuff into ExtJS.
Thanks a lot!